# Pandas read_json converts string to decimal (though it has double quotes enclosing the data)

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I have a JSON file with a field which is supposed to be a string that represents an NPI Number.   The JSON file looks like this:

```
[{ ...
"npi_109":"1234567891",
 ...
}, 
{ ...more records }]
```

I use pandas to read it in like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json("temp/" + file.orig_filename, encoding = 'unicode_escape')
```

I read into a dataframe and then use pyarrow to write to Parquet.  I see that field in parquet gets defined as a decimal.  To get around the issue of the field being read as a decimal (despite the enclosing double quotes in the JSON), I am converting that one column to a string as follows:

```
 df['npi_109'] = df['npi_109'].astype(str)
```

But what ends up happening is the number gets converted to:
"1234567891.0" which is not what we want, so is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Try setting `dtype=str` in `pd.read_json`

Comment: Thanks Ian but that seems to have the unwanted side effect of trying to convert all fields to a string and generating a bunch of "nan"  in the numeric columns that may not have a value for all rows.

Comment: Worse still, make that "99e123456" and you'll get an `inf` out of Pandas :-(

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
df['npi_109'] = df['npi_109'].astype(int).astype(str)
```

Or, if you don't need pandas to infer types when reading the json:

```
df = pd.read_json(filename, encoding = 'unicode_escape', dtype=False)
```

Or, force it to be a string column

```
df = pd.read_json(filename, encoding = 'unicode_escape', dtype={column_name: str})
```

Comment: Thanks the third option worked like a charm!!   I'm mostly a Java developer but needed to write a AWS lambda function to do some JSON to Parquet conversions and thought Python would be quick and easy (except for a few little battles like this one).

Comment: Good answers, but I consider this a Pandas bug that we're working around.

Comment: I agree. The types from a json file should be preserved by default